# No operator == matches these operands

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
    int x;
    const int Maxword = 5;
    std::string Guess[Maxword];
    std::string words[Maxword] = {
        "Hello",
        "World",
        "Shift",
        "Green",
        "Seven"
    };
    srand(time(NULL));
    int iSecret = rand() % 4 + 1;
    std::string Cool(words[iSecret]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << Cool[i] << std::endl;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << ("Please enter the letters you would like to guess") << std::endl;
        std::cin >> Guess[i];
        std::cout << Guess[i] << std::endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (Guess[i] == Cool[i]) {
            std::cout << Guess[i] << "Is in the word";
        }

    }
```

For this statement here at the Bottom for statement within the if statement it has a no operator dont mind the actual code it is just a rough draft before I make the actual code but i dont see the problem.

Comment: `if (Guess[i] = Cool[i])` is a common mistake, use == for comparison

Comment: oh aha sorry I actually have the double equals in my code dont know why it was single but the issue still persists

Comment: The exact error code is  : C++ no operator matches these operands            operand types are: std::string == char

Comment: `Cool` is a string, `Guess` is a string array.

Comment: Cool is a string. Cool[i] is a single character. You are comparing a string with a single char.

Comment: so in my case how do i make Guess into a character array

Comment: You still haven't fixed `int iSecret = rand() % Maxword;` from your last question. You will never select `"Hello"` with `4 + 1`. See answer to your last question.

Comment: Done so now thank you for the correction for that I never actually realised that

Answer (score 1):

`Cool` is a string. `Cool[i]` is a character. `Guess` is an array of strings. `Guess[i]` is a string.  You're trying to compare a character to a string. You probably mean `if (guess[i] == Cool)`